# Select part of string from text file and write it to another with powershell

Tags: string, powershell, cut

i´m currently working on a script that reads out the standard printer on a workstation and write it to a textfile. Now i need to convert or cut the output string and write it to another file in order to set the cutted string as new default printer.

e.g. first textfile content is something like this:

> \NDPS-mydomain\myprinter.ou.cn.mydomain.de

I'd like to get this:

> PS-myprinter

The amount of characters of "myprinter" is different from printer to printer.

I'm stuck at cutting the parts I need out from the complete string.

Background:I´ve did a big printserver migration from novell to microsoft. In order to affect the users less than possible, i want to set the new microsoft deployed printer with this script as default printer again. Hope this is understandable.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks in advance

sample code so far:

```
$name = (get-content env:Computername)

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true" | 
    Select-Object - expandProperty Name | 
    Out-File  -filepath C:\"$name"_defaultprinter.txt

Get-Content "C:\"$name"_defaultprinter.txt" | 
    Foreach-Object {$_.Replace("NDPS","PS")} | 
    Set-Content "C:\"$name"_defaultprinter.txt"
```

Here is the output:

`\\mydomain\NDPS-MJP1-0014-SamsungML3471.A-Printers.MJP1.xx-xxxx.xxxxx-xxxxx.DE`
`\\mydomain\NDPS-MJP1-0014-SamsungML3471.A-Printers.MJP1.xx-xxxx.xxxxx-xxxxx.DE`

Output should be only the `PS-MJP1-0014-SamsungML3471`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script instead:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true" | % {
    $_.Name -replace '(?:.*)\\NDPS-([^\.]+)(?:.*)', 'PS-$1'
} | Out-File  -FilePath "C:\$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_defaultprinter.txt"
```

**EDIT**: Try running this on one computer. Post all the output as an edit to YOUR question(not in a comment). If you need to hide some sensitive information, just replace the words(leave special characters etc.):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true" | % {
    $_.Name

    $_.Name -replace '(?:.*)\\NDPS-(?:[^\\]+)\\(.+?)\.(?:.*)', 'PS-$1'
}
```

The regex I provided works perfect with one of your samplestrings, so it seems the actual value of `$_.Name` is not equal to the sample you provided. So run the code above and provide output as I said so we get a correct sample.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I will try this on thursday because i´m on holidays at the moment. I will post the result directly after testing on thursday.

Comment: Hello again, yesterday i was not able to test. But today I did and the replacing doesn´t work. The out-file contains the following string:\\mydomain\NDPS-myprinter.ou.cn.mydomain.de this is the same format as it is stored in the system. But out-file should look like this: PS-myprinter only. It was a bit wrong in my inital post. Sorry fro that.

Comment: It did just that when I tried your sample as a normal string. . Try $test = $_.Name inside the foreachloop(% { ... Here .... } ). Then after the loop. Output the variable with and without the replace-command.   Supply all output in an edit to your question.

Comment: I´m not sure if I understand you correctly. I tryed:Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer -Filter "Default = $true" | % {
    $test = $_.Name -replace '(?:.*)\\NDPS-(?:[^\\]+)\\(.+?)\.(?:.*)', 'PS-$1'
} | Out-File  -FilePath "C:\$($env:COMPUTERNAME)_defaultprinter.txt" and generated textfile is empty. The result when removing the -replace command is also an empty textfile. When using your first suggestion in the answer above then the output is:\\bamitte\NDPS-myprinter.A-printer.bla.blabla.mydomain.de

Comment: Dear Graimer, is it possible to post a pm? I don´t want to post the complete domain string here.

Comment: see the updated I posted with code you can run to provide the output I need. You should hide the domain name, but as said, leave special-characters etc. as it was :-)

Comment: Thanks for your patience :-) Output is posted above

Comment: As you can see, your output now is not equal to the sample you provided. ;) I'll fix it in an hour or so. Just need to get home.

Comment: Thank you so much ;-) I will leave too and try your new version on monday. Wish you a nice weekend.

Comment: Hey Graimer, now i´ve checked the code you´ve provided and everything works fine. Thank you for your help. You did a great job ;-) Best Regards, Spagusi